# Service not found using its component name

Tags: android, service

I'm stuck with a service, which can't be found using it's explicit component name in the starting intent sent by startService().
The classes are in the same project and package. The explicit service calling with its component name is intentional, because it's supposed to be a private service, and the startService/stopService method instead of the bindService is intentional too, because the service should run in the background without any activity communicating with it.
Must be a stupid mistake, but I spent 2 days looking for it and no luck yet. I have an other project too, which uses the same service calling method and it works, compared the two multiple times, but no real difference.
What can I be possibly be doing wrong?

```
//main activity which controls the service
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //...
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Logger01Service.class);
  startService(intent);
  //...
 }
```

The error in the debugger's log:

```
11-23 11:07:28.711: WARN/ActivityManager(1279): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.biroalex.test.logger/.LoggerService }: not found
```

What can I be possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared it in the AndroidManifest.xml?
from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html :

> Each service class must have a
>   corresponding   declaration
>   in its package's AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an entry in AndroidManifest.xml about your each Activity or Service. I think you are missing this. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Example from API DEMO manifest file:

```
   <service android:name=".app.ForegroundService" />
```